# How to use Haskells laziness when finding right triangles

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I'm following the (excellent) Haskell tutorial at http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out and am trying out the right triangle example:

```
> let triangles = [(a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..10], a <- [1..10], a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

running this I get, as expected:

```
> triangles 
[(4,3,5),(3,4,5),(8,6,10),(6,8,10)]
```

Now, I'd like to try using infinite lists instead:

```
> let triangles = [(a,b,c) | c <- [1..], b <- [1..], a <- [1..], a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

But when I try it, like:

```
> take 2 triangles
```

...the programs just runs and runs with no output. What am I doing wrong? I thought Haskells laziness would cause it to find the two first triangles and then halt?

Comment: It does take the first 2 right triangles and then halt. It just never gets to the first 2 right triangles. What you're trying to do is akin to defining the integers as (1,2,...,-1,-2,...). This doesn't work because the part before -1 is infinite.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the laziness isn't the problem here. It's the order in which you're iterating the variables in the list.

Basically what happens is:

1. c is bound to 1
2. b is bound to 1
3. a is bound to 1
4. Equation is checked
5. a is bound to 2
6. Equation is checked
7. a is bound to 3
8. Equation is checked

and it goes on forever.

So the generator keeps on iterating and binding values for `a`, because it doesn't know that you need to stop and also increment `b` or `c` for a change.

So you need to generate tuples in more balanced ways.

You can use, for instance, this method:

```
triplesN :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
triplesN n = [(i, j, n - i - j) | i <- [1..n - 2], 
                                  j <- [1..n - i - 1], i>=j, 
                                  let k = n - i - j,   j>=k]

isTriangle (a, b, c) = a^2 == b^2 + c^2

triangles = filter isTriangle $ concatMap triplesN [1..]
```

`tripleN` generates all the ordered triples with sum `n`. By mapping this function over all the natural numbers we actually get the stream of all ordered pairs. And finally, we filter only those triples that are triangles.

By doing:

```
take 10 triangles
```

we get:

`[(5,4,3),(10,8,6),(13,12,5),(15,12,9),(17,15,8),(20,16,12),(25,24,7),(25,20,15),(26,24,10),(29,21,20)]`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Something like that helps:
    
`> let triangles = [(a,b,c) | c <- [1..], b <- [1..c], a <- [1..c], a^2 + b^2 == c^2]`

Comment: Oh wow, I proposed a solution, but yours is even simpler and better.

Answer (score 6):

You may be interested in reading the article [A Monad for Combinatorial Search](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/07/monad-for-combinatorial-search-with.html) on sigfpe's blog.

He defines a new monad called a *Penalty List* or *PList*, similar to the list monad, but which also has the concept of a penalty for more complex solutions. When you combine PLists, the order that the results are generated is the order smallest penalty --> largest penalty.

In your example, the penalty associated with an integer could be equal to the size of the integer, and the penalty associated with a tuple is the sum of the penalties of its elements. So the tuple `(3,4,5)` has penalty 3+4+5 = 12, and the tuple `(5,12,13)` has penalty 5+12+13 = 30.

With the list monad, the order of the tuples produced is

```
(1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,1,3), (1,1,4), (1,1,5) ...
```

and you never see a tuple not of the form `(1,1,x)`. With the PList monad, the tuples produced might be

```
(1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,2,1), (2,1,1), (1,1,3), (1,3,1), (3,1,1), (1,2,2) ...
```

with all 'smaller' tuples generated before 'larger' ones.

For your particular problem this solution is overkill, but it can be very useful in more complex problems.